# HTML listing product properties

Tags: html, text, alignment, indentation

I would like to list product properties like the following way:

Property 1:     Item

Property 2:     Item

Property 3:     Item

Property 4432:  Item

Notice that "Item" starts kind of indented.

I know this can be accomplished with using tables and divs. However they seem to be a little bit of a overkill to me. Can someone tell me how this is commonly implemented?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definition list would be appropriate here:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Property</dt>
    <dd>The related item</dd>
    <dt>Property2 </dt>
    <dd>The second related item</dd>
</dl>
```

To make that list display exactly as you show in your question use the following CSS:

```
dl dt {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

dl dd + dt, dl dd + dd {
    clear: left
}

dl dd + dd {
    float: none
}
```

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jolora/N5Zkd/

Alternatively a simple unordered list would produce cleaner code albeit a little less semantic:

```
<ul>
    <li>Property <span>The related item</span></li>
    <li>Property 2 <span>The related item</span></li>
</ul>
```

The span tags allow you to add CSS to apply the indentation. If no extra than one space indentation is needed then remove the span tags.

Comment: Dear Joe, thanks for the answer. However I have a small problem using the dl dd method, because if I have "The second related item" and it's very big, like a description, the text of the dd would actually be on a new line, without the indentation. I would like to have the dd items be indented if it spans over more than 1 line.

Comment: Try setting a height on both elements like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jolora/N5Zkd/7/ - the height just needs to be big enough to contain the largest piece of content.